How to avoid the strange line at the end of a zigzag decoration
I would like to place a specified number of zigzags along a path. 
That means, in the following MWE are exactly 4 positive and 4 negativ amplitudes around the black line.
How can I avoid the strange line at the end of a zigzag decoration?

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\u{2*pi*\r}% Length
\pgfmathsetmacro\s{\u/4}% 4 zigzags over length

\draw[blue, rounded corners]
decorate[decoration={zigzag,segment length=\s*1cm,amplitude=4.5mm,
%post=lineto,post length=0pt % no effect
}
] { (0,0) -- (\u,0)  
};

\draw (0,0) -- (\u,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This is because of the rounded corners option, which rounds off the end of the curve. Try decoration=snake without rounded corners

Looks better, but there is an important point: "I would like to place a specified number of zigzags along a path."; I added:
"That means, in the following MWE are exactly 4 positive and 4 negativ amplitudes around the black line. "

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaredecoration{rigrag}{up from center}{%
  \state{up from center}[width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength, next state=big down]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }%
  \state{big down}[switch if less than=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to center finish,
                   width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                   next state=big up]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }%
  \state{big up}[switch if less than=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to center finish,
                 width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                 next state=big down]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }%
  \state{center finish}[width=0pt, next state=final]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }%
  \state{final}
  {
  %  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast} %do not draw final lineto
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\u{2*pi*\r}% Length
\pgfmathsetmacro\s{\u/4}% 4 zigzags over length
\draw[red, decoration={rigrag, segment length=\s cm, amplitude=4.5mm}, decorate, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (\u,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (\u,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


As @cfr correctly writes, the code is copied and modified from
texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex


Would you mind adding the file where you got the code to modify? (I'm assuming you modified zigzag to produce rigrag.) There are so many files in pgf/tikz, I think it would help people who don't know where to look. (I assume pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex, although it's also an example in the docs, so maybe the relevant file for that or, even, pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex.)

Thanks a lot. I would like to get to the bottom of 'segment length' in more detail, so I created a follow-up question here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/720997/46023
