TikZ-decoration: How to to draw a defined number of positive and negative amplitudes over a certain length
I would like to use decoration=snake (or possibly coil, aspect=0) to draw a defined number \n of positive and negative amplitudes over a length \u (in the example n=4).
How do I have to set the segment length (\s) for this?
I set a segement length of \pgfmathsetmacro\s{\u/4} for example for 4 positive and 4 negative amplitudes; but there stays a gap...

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\u{3.456}% Length
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{4}% No. of  pos. and neg. ampitudes
% segment lenght:
\pgfmathsetmacro\s{\u/\n}% wanted: \n pos. and \n neg. ampitudes along \u

\draw[blue]
decorate[decoration={
snake, 
%coil, aspect=0, % alternativ
segment length=\s*1cm, amplitude=7.5mm,
}
] { (0,0) -- (\u,0)  
};

% x-axis: 
\draw[|-|] (0,0) node[below]{0} node[above=11mm, anchor=west]{n=\n} -- (\u,0) node[below]{u};

% Help line for \s:
\draw[red, -|] (0,0) -- (\s,0) node[above]{s}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


According to the manual, it draws a sine wave 'softened' at the ends. So it's looking, for example, for whether there is at least 0.625 segment lengths remaining before deciding whether to switch to drawing a simple line or whether to start another segment. If you actually need a sine wave, you probably don't want a snake. If, on the other hand, you actually want a snake, you probably need a different calculation here. Could you clarify?

The decoration isn't an exact sine. The ends are 'softened'. So, when pgf calculates whether it has room for another segment or half-segment, it looks to see if it has, say, 0.625 or 0.8125 of the segment length left. So you need to reduce the segment length to account for this. For example,
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\u{3.456}% Length
    \pgfmathsetmacro\n{4}% No. of  pos. and neg. ampitudes
    % segment lenght:
    \pgfmathsetmacro\s{(\u-0.125)/\n}% wanted: \n pos. and \n neg. ampitudes along \u
    
    \draw[blue]
    decorate[decoration={
      snake, 
      segment length=\s*1cm, amplitude=7.5mm,
    }
    ] { (0,0) -- (\u cm,0)  
    };
    
    % x-axis: 
    \draw[|-|] (0,0) node[below]{0} node[above=11mm, anchor=west]{n=\n} -- (\u,0) node[below]{u};
    
    % Help line for \s:
    \draw[red, -|] (0,0) -- (\s,0) node[above]{s}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

gets 4 periods with room for the softening at each end.

If you actually need a sine wave, however, you shouldn't use snake because the decoration will distort the path at both ends.
EDIT
The following method of calculating s seems to work for n=1,...,10. I say 'seems' because I didn't go through the code to figure out whether this is actually the correct calculation or not.

Note that the -1pt adjustment is needed to account for the imprecision of TeX arithmetic. It is possible a larger adjustment might be needed if n gets significantly larger.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721011/ addaswyd o gwestiwn cis: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/720997/
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newdimen\u
  \newdimen\s
  \pgfmathsetlength\u{3.456cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\n{7}% No. of  pos. and neg. ampitudes
  \foreach \n in {1,...,10}
  {
    % segment lenght:
    \pgfmathsetlength\s{(\u-1pt)/(0.125+\n)}% wanted: \n pos. and \n neg. ampitudes along \u
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-25*\n mm]
      \draw[blue]
      decorate[decoration={
        snake, 
        segment length=\s, amplitude=7.5mm,
      }
      ] { (0,0) -- (\u,0)  
      };
      
      % x-axis: 
      \draw[|-|] (0,0) node[below]{0} node[above=11mm, anchor=west]{n=\n} -- (\u,0) node[below]{u};
      
      % Help line for \s:
      \draw[red, -|] (0,0) -- (\s,0) node[above]{s}; 
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Mmmh, it might be difficult to work this out for any n=3,4,5,6,7,...
And yes, I specifically want a decoration; Plotting a normal sine wouldn't be a problem.

@cis What I mean is that if you want a decoration which is a sine wave, snake won't cut it. If you want a decoration which is somewhat-sine-wave-ish, snake will likely do the job. And, yes, the calculations are trickier because you can't do simple division.

@cis Please see edit above.

Hehe, I see. Very tricky. I will work with that nearby.

@cis Actually, the calculation was as bad as I thought. I expected I might have to figure out what the various bits of code were doing first, but guessing was quicker. (I took the numbers from the code. I just wasn't sure which one I needed. The first wasn't it. The second fit.) But I confused myself for a while by forgetting to allow for imprecision, which meant tests I thought ought to pass failed abysmally :(. That 1pt adjustment is vital to your sanity ;).

By the way, that was the point of all the curiosity: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721117/46023
But I finally decided on the decoration coil, aspect=0.
In all cases, the translation time is significantly reduced with the decoration method (compared to the start post method); So each one can paint a sine... :)
